# Loop Cut and Slide in Blender 2.74

Tags: modeling, mesh

This may be a dumb question, but did Loop Cut and Slide get removed with Blender 2.74? I have 2.73 and 2.74 both on my computer, and it works fine on the old one, but when I go to User Preferences and try to change the key it's mapped to in the new one, it's just not listed at all. I tried resetting to factory defaults and uninstalling/reinstalling, but the option still isn't there.

Edit: I should mention my OS is Windows 7 64-bit with the installed version of Blender, not the portable exe. When I try to use Ctrl + R on a mesh, nothing happens. I've attached a screenshot of what happens when I go to Input prefs and search for actions using the shortcut "Ctrl R" in 2.74

[image: Screeenshot of Blender 2.73 showing the option to map "Loop Cut and Slide" to a key]

[image: Screeenshot of Blender 2.74 showing no option for "Loop Cut and Slide"]
[image]

Comment: No, it most certainly did not get removed. In edit mode what happens when you press `Ctrl` `R`?

Comment: You have to change to Key Binding

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise is this a bug ?

Comment: @Chebhou I don't think so, need more info from the OP to be sure though. Could be.

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise does it show up when you type "loop" ?

Comment: @Chebhou Ah yes! Hmm, unless it is not compatible with non-Windows OS's then I think it is a bug.

Comment: maybe case sensitive ?

Comment: @APant can you run this in the console to see what it outputs `bpy.ops.mesh.loopcut_slide`

Comment: You should get a result like this: `# Cut mesh loop and slide it
bpy.ops.mesh.loopcut_slide(MESH_OT_loopcut={"number_cuts":1, "smoothness":0, "falloff":'ROOT', "edge_index":-1, "mesh_select_mode_init":(False, False, False)}, TRANSFORM_OT_edge_slide={"value":0, "mirror":False, "snap":False, "snap_target":'CLOSEST', "snap_point":(0, 0, 0), "snap_align":False, "snap_normal":(0, 0, 0), "correct_uv":False, "release_confirm":False})`

Comment: I ran it several times (edit mode with edges selected, then with no selection, object mode with selection, then with no selection) and always got the same result:  
>>> bpy.ops.mesh.loopcut_slide
`# Cut mesh loop and slide it
bpy.ops.mesh.loopcut_slide(MESH_OT_loopcut={"number_cuts":1, "smoothness":0, "falloff":'ROOT', "edge_index":-1, "mesh_select_mode_init":(False, False, False)},
 TRANSFORM_OT_edge_slide={"value":0, "mirror":False, "snap":False, "snap_target":'CLOSEST', "snap_point":(0, 0, 0), "snap_align":False, "snap_normal":(0, 0, 0), "correct_uv":False, "release_confirm":False})`

Comment: that means it is enabled , you have to create the shortcut by yourself

Comment: The entry from ***User Preferences***➞***Input*** was gone, so I just had to create a new entry ( Shortcut ) where the command was set to `mesh.loopcut_slide`, and then I set my shortcut key.

Comment: @Chebhou Post that as an answer

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you are using a custom keyboard shortcut preset. The default is called "Blender":

[image]

If you reset to factory settings in *File > Load Factory Settings* does it appear? This won't be permanent unless you save your startup .blend, so you can check to see if it's there without deleting your customized setup.

Also check to see if the operator is there by pressing <kbd>Space</kbd> in the *3D view* while in edit mode and typing in "loop":

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the Input tab, change the search type to *Key-Binding* and type `Ctrl R`. You should now see a result similar to this:

[image: Example]

The command you are looking for is the second from the top.

I got this result with Blender 2.74 on Windows. Note that if this doesn't bring it up, you must have done something specific to disable it. Either that or it is not supported for your specific OS.

Comment: Weird as it is, it's not there. I noticed this as soon as I first tried 2.74, older versions have always and still do work fine. I don't know how I could have disabled it, but I suppose it's possible, though I would think it wouldn't survive a reset to factory settings. I edited toe original post to include my OS and a screenshot of what happens when I search for Ctrl R, just like your screenshot.

Comment: @APant1 I am using the default build, and it shows up and is enabled by default. What OS are you running?

Comment: Windows 7 64-bit. I've looked through the whole list of commands under File> User Preferences> Input> 3D View> Mesh, and "Loop Cut and Slide" isn't listed at all. I looked through the rest of the 3D view section, and didn't find it there either.

Comment: @APant1 *did* you reset to factory settings?