# Find commands by name in blender 2.80 beta?

Tags: customization, shortcut

[Find commands by name](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40163/find-commands-by-name)

The question is very similar - where is this search popup in 2.80 beta and how to call it? Suggested `Spacebar` doesn't work

I opened `Preferences` and found a search popup in it with `F3` keyboard button.

But this menu is different or I don't understand how it work...

**Example**

[Loop Cut and Slide in Blender 2.74](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28913/loop-cut-and-slide-in-blender-2-74)

[image: picture]

Command "Loop Cut and Slide" exists but search menu called with `F3` doesn't contain it (in other words I can't find a command from this picture). Or is it just a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you have the mesh selected and that you are in "edit mode"?
Otherwise the operator will not show up.